# Create a CSS only Popup, with fade and effect

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to create a CSS based popup (CSS3 Allowed) without any JavaScript, with a fade transition and scale effect. Something similar to IceCream Sandwitch and **JellyBean** popup messages.

I have tried the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/7UaK4/5/

Main Parts of Code:

**HTML**

```
<span class="info"> Info </span>
<div class="message">
    <p>
        Content
    </p>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.message {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9, .9);
    -webkit-transition: all .18s ease-in-out;
}
.info:hover + .message {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

What I am doing is setting the `opacity` of the element to `0`, and on `hover` of a sibling DOM element, transtion it to `1`.
How do I position it in center, both vertically and horizontally?
Also, is this the proper way to make a CSS3 popup?
Can I transition from `display: none` to `display: block` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I position it in center, both vertically and horizontally?

Essentially, you would push the popup 50% from the top and left. However, you must go backwards a bit, since you must take into account the width and height of the popup.

```
.center-of-screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;     margin-top:  /* -(height/2) */;
    left: 50%;    margin-left: /* -(width/2) */;
}
```

*Source:* [How to center an object exactly in the center?](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)

***Note:*** `-(height/2)` and `-(width/2)` are negative values of half of element's width and height. E.g. if your element is `300px x 200px` code is:

```
.center-of-screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;     margin-top:  -100px;
    left: 50%;    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

---

> Also, is this the proper way to make a CSS3 popup?

Yes, if you are talking about a hover popup.

---

> Can I transition from display: none to display: block ?

No. You would go from `display: none` to `display: block` with `transition` only on `opacity`.

Comment: Sorry for delay in accepting answer. Thanks for CSS-tricks link for positioning in center. I used once but forgot that :)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now by using `visibility`:

```css
.message {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;

    transform: scale(.9);

    transition: transform .18s, opacity .18s, visibility 0s .18s; // delay visibility
}

.info:hover + .message {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```